# How do I calculate the ranking of some galleries based on the rankings of the artists represented by them?

Tags: descriptive-statistics, ranking, weighted-mean, winsorizing

The mean is not good in this case, because there are galleries that have an artist with a high rank and several other artists with way lower ranks. I'm thinking about doing a weighted mean, but I don't know how to split the weights to the ranking ranges. Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: This really depends on what you are trying to get with the rankings and the nature of the artist rankings. I am assuming that there are known "artist ranks", but are these 1, 2, 3 .... (and who's number 1? Da Vinci?) or "great", "near great"... Or what?

And do you  want to weight for number of paintings? Does having 1 Van Gogh make up for having 100 by notalent noname?

And

Comment: The ranks are numbers (1, 2, 3 and so on). Number 1 is Andy Warhol actually. I don't have the number of paintings, so they don't weigh in. I don't have to computer the ranks of the artists anyway. I have them already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about simply summing the *qualities* of the artists, where ranks are probably not the best measure for the quality, but if that's all you have...

Isn't it the case that a gallery with ten soso artists is better than one with five soso artists?

Also think about whether a gallery with ten works of a single artist is better than a gallery with five works of the same artist (if you have access to this information).

Answer (score 3):

Maybe just quote the top one and say how many of their works are there. The quantity of art is quite important isn't it?

Summary statistic of all ranks: if you have outliers at the top you may want to use a robust measure. Look up robust statistics on wikipedia. These include the median and trimmed means, or Winsorization.

Comment: I don't have a number for their works. I'll look at your other suggestions.

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to Robust Measures, although the Wikipedia article is not easy to digest!